# What is this storm-window part called?

Tags: windows, old-house, window-frame

I removed all my ancient triple-stack storm windows to paint my house, but as I’m reinstalling them I misplaced one of the metal shims that holds the entire storm frame into place. This thin piece of metal sits on the sill, and then the storm window frame slides onto it, effectively lifting the frame up an inch so it fits directly into the house window frame. After extensive googling I can’t find any information on it, find pictures of it, and google image search won’t ID it. Looking to find/buy a replacement, any ideas where to look/what to do?[image]

Comment: It almost looks like a door sweep.

Comment: Hard to tell from that distance. Maybe borrow one from another window, temporarily install it to get this storm window set at the right height, then put the borrowed one back. Once done, fill the gap with "something" like some aluminum flashing.

Comment: @SteveSh I wish it was a door sweep! It does look like one though..

Comment: @FreeMan Eh yeah sorry, not the greatest pic - I'll get another from the outside in the morning. I was hoping to avoid removing any of the windows that I've already installed, but that may be the only option at this point if nobody can ID it. I could have a friend just lift it into place as I install it, but that shim seems to hold most of the frame weight. Filling the gap would help insulate, but I think it would need to be structural too. Maybe I can find a metal shop to fab something up.. not sure if that's a pricey option though.